# ERROR:jQuery.verto.init is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mod-verto

I'm using a Verto library in my nodejs console based project - I've added all necessary references to main.js file - something like this:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const $= require('jquery');
const verto= require('verto/src/jquery.verto');
```

when I use an HTML file and use these references as a script in the HTML file my project works fine .but when excluding the HTML file and changing the project to console-based it gives an error related to veto.init.